# Script not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, lightbox

```
function loadPopup(type) {
    if (type == "login") {
        $("#login").show();
        $("#dark").show();
        $("body").keypress(function (e) {
            var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
            if (key == "27") {
                $("#login").hide();
                $("#dark").hide();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This popups a window which have id login and dark. When Esc is pressed this will be automatically closed. Style of both elements:

```
#dark {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0 % ;
    left: 0 % ;
    width: 100 % ;
    height: 100 % ;
    background-color: #aaa;
    z-index: 1001; 
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: .80;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 80);

}
#login {
    display: none;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50 % ;
    left: 50 % ;
    margin-left: -250px;
    margin-top: -250px;
    z-index: 1002;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<head>
<title>some title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/css.php?file=index" type="text/css"/>

    <script src="script/JQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/js.php?file=index" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
        <div id="dark"></div>
        <div id="login"></div>
```

And some elements here.

This worked in IE 9, Mozilla Firefox but not in Chrome 21. Where is the error?

Comment: "where is the error?" => In the error console, press F12, or Menu->Tools->JavaScript Console.

Comment: the error is Uncaught TypeError: Property 'login' of object [object Window] is not a function

Comment: login isn't used in the code above, it must be in some other code, look for that word, sounds like it is not initialized / created properly (or in the right place)

Comment: Also where are you calling the function loadPopup(type)

Comment: It's working: http://jsfiddle.net/GomatoX/vxMxS/1/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be assigning the keypress event event time the function is called.. Try moving it outside the function..

```
$(function() {
   $("body").keypress(function (e) {
       var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
       if (key == "27") {
            $("#login").hide();
            $("#dark").hide();
        }
    });
});

function loadPopup(type) {
    if (type == "login") {
        $("#login").show();
        $("#dark").show();
    }
}
```